# PDO Inert Into On Duplicate Key with condition not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Everything works fine except i have to check only update existing record if database score is < new score. When i add WHERE score < :score' i get problem. How to add condition to check database score is less than new score?

```
try {
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO UserTable (fb_id, level, score, star, timestamp) ' .
    'VALUES(:fb_id, :level, :score, :star, :timestamp)' .
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score= :score, timestamp= :timestamp WHERE score < :score');
    //WHERE score < $score
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $fb_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':level', $level);
    $stmt->bindParam(':score', $score);
    $stmt->bindParam(':star', $star);
    $stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $current_time);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }
}
```

Comment: Use an `IF` for the value.

Comment: Insert does not support the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO UserTable (fb_id, level, score, star, timestamp) ' .
     VALUES(:fb_id, :level, :score, :star, :timestamp)' .
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         score = GREATEST(:score, score),
         timestamp = (CASE WHEN :score > score THEN :timestamp ELSE timestamp END);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. The larger of the existing value and the new one is used for the update. In the `MAX()` function, `score` refers to the existing value, and `VALUES(score)` refers to the new value.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO UserTable (fb_id, level, score, star, timestamp) ' .
'VALUES(:fb_id, :level, :score, :star, :timestamp)' .
'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = GREATEST(score, VALUES(score)), timestamp= :timestamp');
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Syntax looks right but probably have some issue with my sql version 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24
I am getting this error -
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' VALUES(score)), timestamp= '1541781260'' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, `MAX()` is an aggregate function, `GREATEST()` is what I should have put. Answer is updated.